# sklearn is not imported due to a .dll failure

Tags: python, scikit-learn

With Miniconda 4.5.11 and python 3.6.6, sklearn module was working fine.
But things stopped working after I installed tensorflow.

While I saw some discussions similar to this, but in my env, package mkl is already installed. 
numpy=1.15.4
mkl=2019.0
scikit-learn              0.20.0
scipy                     1.1.0

Error :

```
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 22, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 83, in <module>
    from scipy.special import boxcox  # noqa
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 640, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working after trying various things.

This is what I did :
**install/upgrade pandas, numpy, scikit-learn 

set PATH=C:\Miniconda3\envs\py36\Library\bin;%PATH%**

Probably the tensorflow installation steps kept library dlls like libifcoremd.dll only in the new env for tensorflow. And removed from Library\bin of Miniconda3